# Are there any relevant use case for React Render Props and HOC with functional components?

Tags: reactjs, components, web-component, high-order-component

I know [it's possible to use RRP and HOC patterns with functional components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481733/hocs-and-render-props-with-functional-components-in-react-16#:%7E:text=Both%20render%20props%20and%20HOC,a%20function%20which%20returns%20JSX.), my question actually is, are there any point on doing that? Making some researches I read React/Custom Hooks can essentially handle what render props did in the past with Class Components. The fact is there is not very much information about these patterns in relation to Functional Components, almost every example out there use Class Components, so I was wondering if there's a **relevant** place to it in Functional Composition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is how I would put it: In most of the cases, you would use hooks; in some specific situations you may use, higher-order components.

From a control perspective, hooks provide more flexibility for the user of the code. It means there is a possibility that they could be used in not-intended way. But I would call it a theoretical possibility.

If your reusable logic has JSX as well as some custom logic, may be providing higher-order component or, even render props, makes more sense. Of course this means, that you should have extremely well defined lifecycle for your component and you would not like to provide complete control to the user.

An example would be `react-router` which is combination of both hooks and render props where applicable.